# Could bootstrapping and other numerical methods allow us to bypass linear regression assumptions?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model

I'm trying to get a complete understanding of the classical linear regression model.  Specifically I am trying to understand what assumption is needed to do what and what happens if assumptions are violated.

I am looking at the derivation for b0 and b1 using the least squares method and it seems like all that is going on is minimizing sum of squares, which shouldn't require any assumptions.  In other words, estimating b0 and b1 using least squares estimation does not need errors to be normal, iid, constant variance, etc...  as it's purely optimization via calculus.

Now if we want to use b0 and b1 to estimate the true Beta0 and Beta1 and make predictions, my understanding is that we DO require assumptions (like normality, constant variance, iid etc...) to hold.  But this is only because we have formulas that generate the standard errors of coefficients and these rely on the assumptions.  Prediction and everything else relies on these standard errors as well and thus ultimately we need the assumptions to hold.  This makes sense if we want to analytically build the model.  In the old days, this is all we could do as we don't have fast computers.

But today, with cloud computing, can these assumptions be relaxed?  Theoretically, could we build a linear model with little to no assumptions about the data other than that the true relationship between X and Y is linear and follows a constant distribution?  Let's say true Y | X follows a skewed beta distribution.

I would imagine we could still use least squares to obtain b0 and b1 estimate.  Then we can probably use bootstrap resampling to construct the sampling distributions for b0 and b1.  And then somehow we could use that to predict?  Not sure what math to use to link sampling distributions and point estimates and generate confidence intervals for prediction...

So for such a model, the only things that need to hold are, linear relationship between Y and X and that the distribution of Y | X is the same for all X.

Is the reasoning correct?  And thus all the issues with non normality, non constant variance, multicollinearity, really only arise because we are trying to solve things analytically and quickly go from b0 and b1 estimates to prediction via pre-derived formulas.

Comment: My understanding is that linearity between X and Y is still required and can be obtained through a transformation if not met. However, constant variance of the residuals can be relaxed. When constant variance is violated, the coefficients are still unbiased but any inference conducted using their SE (i.e. t-test, confidence intervals) will be incorrect. When the assumption is violated, you can use bootstrapping or sandwich estimation to get a robust estimate of the SEs.

Comment: I'm saving your question. Tomorrow i will answer you

Comment: I've removed the "generalized linear models" tag, which refers to the use of exponential family distributions and is not a synonym for "classical linear regression model". "linear model" $=$ "general linear model" $\ne$ "generalize linear model".